# An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden - Why I'm receiving this error when I try to post an item at AWS S3?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm working in an e-commerce Django project and I've made the deployment of the project in an EC2 instance, but now that I'm trying to work again at my Django project I'm receiving this error when I try to create a new item

ClientError at /items/new/
An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Note that I've tried several different types of bucket policies and no one have work

Bucket Policy ->

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::ecommercesimple",
                "arn:aws:s3:::ecommercesimple/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
settings.py ->


# Amazon S3 settings

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxx'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'ecommercesimple'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_NAME = 's3v4',
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_VERITY = True
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Policy you provided explicitly allowing all actions for all accounts! That can be dangerous so revise that.

Here is steps that will help you to troubleshoot problems with getting object headers:

- Check if you have enabled Access control list (ACL). If enabled check read permissions there. It is recommended to disable ACL for you bucket.
- Review Object Ownership setting for an S3 bucket.
- Try access object via curl `curl -v -X HEAD https://ecommercesimple.s3.amazonaws.com/objKey`. If that's working rom EC2, you have problems in your AWS Credentials or setting associated with your identity.
- Check EC2 outbound rules, something like deny policy can cause such troubles.
- Check VPC endpoint policy, so it won't restrict using S3.

Comment: Hey SerhiiH

1 - It's enabled and for some reason I can't edit it, the message says:
"This bucket has the bucket owner enforced setting applied for Object Ownership
When bucket owner enforced is applied, use bucket policies to control access."

2 - Revised and it's ok
3 - Didn't work
4 - Looks like correct
5 - I check too and looks like ok

I try from 0 without create an EC2 instance, but I'm still facing this problem, so I believe it's my AWS account user

I've set S3FullAccess in the IAM, but still not working...